# Partial matching

Tags: php, matching

Is there a built in function or a function that someone has already written that can match names without being exact?

For example, I have:

```
Marry
John
Steve
Steven
Stewie
```

If someone types "stew" the function would return Stewie.
Or if someone types "ry" the function would return Marry.
Or if someone misspells "Marries" the function would still return Marry. (due to being the most similar of them all)
If "Ste" is supplied it can return false but it doesn't really matter to me.

Does anyone know how to write this sort of function or know of one already written? Seeing as this is probably a common thing, I would assume so.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean 'while a user types, it shows matching names', like autocomplete?

Comment: no, I don't mean that. Just a php function that would return a string. I guess it could be used as an autocomplete thingy but I don't think that would be php's forte

Comment: Could you use the PSpell module, and the word list you supply it with is the names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there are some methods to achieve this:

**Built-In methods**

- [Levensthein distance](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)
- [Similarity calculation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)
- Sound specific algorithms: see [soundex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php) and [metaphone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.metaphone.php)
- [PSpell](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pspell.php) (dicitionary based)

**Not Built in methods**

- [LCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) Longest common subsequence
- Letter N-Grams (used sometimes for spellchecking)
- [Levensthein automaton](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Levenshtein-Automata)
- Word lists (just for completeness)

One of those should help you to solve your problem.

The problem of every of those algorithms is that they are not accurate. So you will have a heuristical solution to the problem.

Usually there are pro and cons between distance and sound algorithms. Sound specific algorithms are less accurate(round about 33% accuracy). But fast. Levensthein is much more accurate but slow. At least the php implementation. There are other systems where Levensthein is faster by a large margin (see e.g. [Levensthein Automata](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Levenshtein-Automata). But this automata algorithm is not built in in php).

Probably as a basic hint:

- If you have much unique terms to compare against dont use Similar_text or Levensthein stick with Sound algorithms
- If you have a pretty small set use Levensthein.

Comment: hmm, is there a way to write a function to use all of these at once?

Comment: I would not suggest to use them in combination the only thing what is being used is a sound algorithm in combination with a distance algorithm ... so if you do not find a direct match by sound you calculate the nearest match with a distance method on the sound string.

Comment: Thanks for the great post fyr. Last question: How would this handle special characters such as '@'?

Comment: Sound algorithms will produce weird results while having non natural language. Distance algorithms calculate the similarity basically with weights on Replace/Substitute/Insert actions. So they work well with special characters.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm going to be using this to also match email addresses which contain '@'. So you would recommend using distance?

Comment: Yes as long as the set of words you compare against is not really huge i would. I add some not built in alternatives for completeness

Answer (score 1):

sounds like [soundex()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php) or [metaphone()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.metaphone.php) is what you're looking for. using those, you can calculate a "key" that represents how a word sounds - doing this for all strings you can compare if two words sound the same (optimized for english language).

another possibility would be [levenshtein()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) wich directly calculates the difference between two strings, so you can compare all strings and show the 5 best hits or something like that.